# How do I set a type for a prop in Svelte with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, svelte

I'm trying to adapt [this excellent Svelte virtual list](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/better-svelte-virtual-list) to Typescript. However, I don't quite understand how to make sure that the variables that I pass are of a specific type. Here is the relevant original code:

```html
  <VirtualList items={books} {itemHeight} {containerHeight} {scrollTop} let:item let:dummy let:y>
    <div class="book" class:dummy style="top:{y}px;">
      {#if !dummy}
        #{item.id} - {item.title}
      {/if}
    </div>
  </VirtualList>
```

As you can see, there is `let:item` to pass the items.

What I would like is just pass the item to another component, like so:

```html
{#if !dummy}
  <BookRowEntry {item} />  <!-- where <BookRowEntry/> has: 'export let item: BookClass;`-->
{/if}
```

This works in plain Javascript, but when I switch to Typescript, I get an error:

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'BookClass': pg, indexts(2739)

So how do I specify/make sure that the item that I pass is of a certain class?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the library really were excellent, it would provide proper typing, including a generic `item` with the correct type based on `items`.

Comment: Well, it's better that the other virtual lists that I have found and it does work in JavaScript. Furthermore, REPL doesn't support TypeScript, so I'm really confused about this criticism and, as a beginnner, would genuinely love to see your improvements so I can learn.

Comment: The criticism is that nowadays it is a reasonable expectation that a library provides type information and this one does not, which makes using the library harder than it needs to be.

Comment: (One valid excuse would be that the library is rather old and that back then there was no proper tooling for generating types for a Svelte component library.)

Comment: Well, the last update was 2 years ago... (also, I'm in now position to criticize as I would not know how to do that myself. :/ )

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two options:

- Write your own type declaration for the component that defines a generic parameter for the item type utilized by `items` and the slot property `item`. This requires familiarizing yourself with the various types in the `svelte` package that are used to describe a component interface.
  A good starting point would be to check out the types that are generated when building components via SvelteKit. You can create a component using generics and see how that is transformed (current syntax should be described in the respective [RFC](https://github.com/sveltejs/rfcs/pull/38))
- Hack it by declaring something like `{@const book = any(item)}`, where `any` is just a function that returns the input as `any` so it can be assigned to the property. You could of course also use a more specialized function that just asserts it to be a book instead. (TS syntax is not supported in the template as of now, so it has to be moved to a function in the script. See [this issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4701).)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am afraid that the first option greatly exceeds my capabilities and I'm not sure I quite understand option 2. Are you saying I could also do something like `{@const book = parseBook(item)}`, with `const parseBook = (item: any) : BookClass {...}`?

Comment: Yes, though it is not "parsing", you already know it's a book, you just tell the TS compiler that it is one (you can just `return item as BookClass`).